# How to "reset" or clear cache when calling a REST service in Xpages

Tags: rest, xpages

[image]I have written a pretty straightforward REST service in Domino 9.0.1. I have a view with about 160K records, each record has about 10 field, and the first field is the key.

From time to time I need to make a change to the service, and when I remake the web service call (from the url in my web browser for instance), the data doesn't necessarily change. It seems it is cached on the there server. I believe it is a server issue as I still get the same results even if I switch to another browser. Sometimes I will change my parm and I get DATA FOR THE PREVIOUS PARM I ENTERED. This is terrible.

How can I reset the web service or flush the cache?

Comment: Can you post your code sample? Also: use Charlesproxy, Fiddler or TCPMon to check if the browser sends the request properly and what the http return code is. To solve this you need to move from "seem" to "that's how it is"

Comment: Do you use proxy server?

Answer (score 1):

You have few options:

1) Add unique parameter to REST url, e.g.: `http://hostname/rest/api/endpoint?systemtime=...`
Where you compute systemtime value using `System.currentTimeMillis()`

2) Use HTTP request cache control headers, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching

Comment: Man, I am a bit lost. What does I added "/endpoint?systemtime=..." to the end of my REST call, and I just keep getting the same data. I read the article on wikipedia but I do not understand what I am supposed to do. I will put a screen shot of the Xpage in my original post.

Comment: You can configure Domino to add cache-control response headers using Web Site Rules (see for more information http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_WEB_SITE_RULES.html). Or you can just specify it in java code, if your Rest Service is custom coded:
e.g.: response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 

The additional parameter basically tell the server to treat the request as fresh one.